# Managing "Hearts" when downloading pictures from iPhone to OSX Photos

Tags: macos, iphone, photos

On my iPhone (iPhone 6 with iOS 9.3.4) I routinely use the "heart" tag to mark my favorite pictures. But, when I sync photos with the OSX Photos App (v 1.5) these tags are removed. In reality I only want to sync or keep these flagged photos. Which brings me to my question(s)

**How can I keep the "heart" tags from my iPhone when downloading to the OSX Photos App?**

An even better option would be to ONLY download heart-flagged photos if possible and to delete all no-flagged photos on the iPhone, but perhaps those are covered elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it's possible to plug your phone into your computer and keep your favorites, however you can use iCloud Photo Library to save your photos to the cloud and then sync them to your Mac. [Here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204264) is a link to a site telling your how exactly to do that. FYI, syncing photos sucks a lot of cell data, so make sure both devices are connected to wifi or Ethernet!

Comment: I am syncing Photos via iCloud, and it maintains my favorite tags. This is a good suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @Frysk iCloud does have some nice photos functions.

Comment: Is it possible to only sync favorites to iCloud? Otherwise I'd have to upgrade storage, which is not ideal?

Comment: I'm not sure... try asking a separate question